# Webdriver Exception after text is typed using RobotFramework

Tags: angularjs, robotframework, selenium2library

I'm testing app written with angularjs. When I want to login using 'Input Text' keyword, I get exception:

```
12:13:13.201 INFO Typing text 'user@123123.com' into text field '//label[contains(@ng-class,'username')]/input[@id='input-username']' 
12:13:14.676 FAIL WebDriverException: Message: javascript error: $ is not defined
JavaScript stack:
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
at eval (eval at executeAsyncScript (unknown source), <anonymous>:2:366)
at Browser.self.notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:5757:7)
at eval (eval at executeAsyncScript (unknown source), <anonymous>:2:323)
at eval (eval at executeAsyncScript (unknown source), <anonymous>:2:439)
at executeAsyncScript (<anonymous>:329:26)
at apply.ELEMENT (<anonymous>:345:29)
at callFunction (<anonymous>:237:33)
at apply.ELEMENT (<anonymous>:247:23)
at <anonymous>:248:3
  (Session info: chrome=52.0.2743.116)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.22.397933 (1cab651507b88dec79b2b2a22d1943c01833cc1b),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10586 x86_64)
```

It worked properly sometime ago, but now still fails. Could it be the RF(library) issue or angular?

I've tried to update chromedriver and chrome, as well.

More facts: 
1. everything is ok with present configuration on another applications, 
2. the same configuration works well on another computers,
3. I can't even run it on Firefox - I get message: WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: %s If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.

Maybe it could be caused by some system updates (windows 10)? But, like I've mentioned, tests on other application work fine.

Comment: Did you try with other browser, like Firefox? The error is coming from Webdriver.

Comment: @Helio, I can't even run it on Firefox - I get message:      ebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: %s If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.     More facts: 1. everything is ok with configuration on different applications, 2. the same configuration works well on another computers.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've found the problem and solve it for time being. Basically I had to back to old version ExtendedSelenium2Library (0.4.13). But I don't know how it impacts for current tests.

Comment: Selenium wedriver compatibility is dependent on the ff,chrome and ie vesion as well. Not everything is compatible with everything else.